# Number of integer solutions to a system of equations

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> How many nonnegative integer solutions are there to the pair of equations $x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_6 = 20$ and $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 7$?

Is my reasoning to the above problem correct?

> Take the number of solutions to the latter equation and multiply it to the number of solutions that results from the difference of the two equations. I figured this is because the solution to the former equation relies on the solution of the second solution.

Note: I expected something so elementary would have a duplicate, but I couldn't find one. Let me know if there is and I'll delete the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the number of non-negative integer solutions to
\begin{align}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 & = 20\\
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 & = 7
\end{align}
is same as the number of non-negative integer solutions to
\begin{align}
x_4 + x_5 + x_6 &= 13\\
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 &= 7
\end{align}
Now note that the two equations are independent and hence the number of solutions is $$\# \text{ of solutions to the first equation} \times \# \text{ of solutions to the second equation}$$

Comment: So does my reasoning not work? I imagined a tree, where 1 solution to the second equation results in $n$-many solutions in the first equation; hence why I took the product.

Comment: @Alan: You’re right, but the product that you need to take is the one in Marvis’s solution: each solution to the second equation uses up $7$ of the total of $20$ in the first equation, so your only freedom is to choose $x_4,x_5$, and $x_6$ so as to make their sum $20-7=13$. Your $n$-many is therefore $\binom{13+3-1}{3-1}$-many.